# failed to execute maven test in jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

im trying to test my java project in jenkins execution `mvn clean test` command,  but i got this error message :

Please refer to /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test1/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
    Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
    The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
    Command was /bin/sh -c cd /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test1 && /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -jar /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test1/target/surefire/surefirebooter4409725364462449811.jar /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test1/target/surefire 2019-03-16T14-14-52_472-jvmRun1 surefire1202620073961749502tmp surefire_05802645415730668788tmp
    Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
    Process Exit Code: 1

My POM file :

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
  </parent>

    <groupId>com.selenuim</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
          <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
          <version>27.0.1-jre</version>
         </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>`

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openqa.selenium.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-20080914.225453</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

it's work fine in my local computer, but on jenkins server !!
Im using JDK 1.8, any idea please ?

Comment: any help plz!!!

Comment: Please show your `pom.xml` and test code.

Comment: @mle i updated my question providing POM.xml file

Comment: Thanks but it is not complete, really interesting would be the head section where we can see which Spring Boot version you are using. Also please add your test class with used annotations at class level and your test method itself.

Comment: @mle done,  :) !

Comment: Can you verify, that you use the same JVM locally like on your Jenkins, namely `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64`? Also please give us an insight about your `JAVA_OPTS` and `MAVEN_OPTS` environment variables, both locally and the Jenkins ones.

Comment: im using JDK 1.8 in both side locally and in jenkins,for maven il using version 3.3.9 in both side too

Comment: Thanks for the information… what about the current state of your local and Jenkins' `JAVA_OPTS` environment variables? I'm especially chasing memory settings such as `-Xmx` etc. Additionally please check the free RAM on your Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Setting maven-surefire-plugin version in pom file is the fix for this issue :

```
<plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
</plugin>
```